# Using a $_GET variable for search function with .htaccess rules rewriting the URL variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I am having issues searching for multiple words on my site.

My search function uses a `$_GET` variable for the search like so:

```
$term = $_GET['search'];
$newterm = '%'.$term.'%';

$params = [$newterm];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ?";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
```

I also have a line in my `.htaccess` file which rewrites the URL from something like `search.php?search=search%20term` to `search/search%20term` like so:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This works fine when searching for one word (e.g. 'search' or 'term') but not when searching for multiple words (e.g. 'search term').

When I do this I get a 404 error stating:

```
The requested URL example.com/search/search term.php was not found on this server.
```

The URL, however, does show the `%20` in the address bar instead of the space and no `.php` extension, like so:

```
example.com/search/search%20term
```

It seems to be thinking this is another directory/file rather than a variable in the URL which may be caused by this line in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

### Edit

My full `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/added?$ product.php?id=$1&added=added [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ page.php?page_id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^order/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ order.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the search term getting matched by the second RewriteRule you showed, try putting this line before it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search/.*$ [NC]
```

This will effectively ignore the /search path when processing that rule.

Note, if you have more rules after this that conflict, you may want to move your search RewriteRule higher up in the file instead.

Also, your regex to match the search term needs to allow for spaces too. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9a-zA-Z\s-]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

(Note the `\s` added to the character class)

[View the test](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=309003d9-0152-519b-9842-a45cf266797a).

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I tried what you suggested and am still getting a similar issue. The only difference is the error message no longer has the .php extension. I have added my full .htaccess file above with that line included.

Comment: @PaddyHallihan Thanks for the update of the full .htaccess file. I have updated my answer to tweak the search `RewriteRule`. Also, sorry I forgot to negate the original `RewriteCond` I posted, so update that too.